# ReactJS update state dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, state

I'm trying to update a components state dynamically based on the arguments sent on a callback function.

So, the goal is if the component sends `valueChange('id', 1)`... `this.state.contractLine.id` will be updated to `1` and if the component sends `valueChange('innerLevel.name', 'newName')` `this.state.contractLine.innerLevel.name` will be updated to `newName`

This is the code i'm using (but it's not working like expected).

```
valueChange(statePath, inputValue) {
    var newState = this.state; 

    var stateBeingChanged = this.state['contractLine'];

    var pathList = statePath.split('.');
        for (var i = 0; i < pathList.length; i++) {
            var elem = pathList[i];
            stateBeingChanged = stateBeingChanged[elem];
        }

    stateBeingChanged = inputValue;

    newState['contractLine'] = stateBeingChanged;

    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT --SOLVED--

Just in case someone has the same problem...
I followed `@rauliyohmc` advice and managed to solve the problem with `lodash`.
The code used (much simpler than I ever thought) was:

```
valueChange(statePath, inputValue) {
    var newState = Object.assign({}, this.state['contractLine']);

    _.set(newState, statePath, inputValue);

    this.setState({contractLine: newState});
}
```

Comment: Quickly looking at your code, it seems you are mutating the state. The culprit is `var newState = this.state`, that has the effect of pointing `newState` to the same object reference. Thus, when you do `newState['contractLine'] = stateBeingChanged` you are mutating `this.state`.  Instead do `var newState = Object.assign({}, this.state)` before generating the new object. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same problem... I followed @rauliyohmc advice and managed to solve the problem with lodash. The code used (much simpler than I ever thought) was:

```
valueChange(statePath, inputValue) {
    var newState = Object.assign({}, this.state['contractLine']);

    _.set(newState, statePath, inputValue);

    this.setState({contractLine: newState});
}
```